Get the Power BI Semantic Model GUID for a model newly created with XMLA Script
I am creating a Power BI Semantic Model using an XMLA script.  Once created I want to grab the newly created GUID that is related to that model but am having a hard time doing this.  Here is the code that creates my model.
                   using (AdomdConnection connection = new AdomdConnection($"DataSource={workspaceConnection};User ID=app:{ApplicationId}@{Tenant};Password={ApplicationSecret};"))
                   {
                       // Open the connection
                       connection.Open();

                       var command = connection.CreateCommand();
                       command.CommandText = xmlaScript;
                       command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                   }

I was using the below command immediately afterwards to snag the GUID but it is inconsistent.  even though I can see the newly created model in power bi service this doesn't always find it.
Model newWorkItemDataset = server.Databases.GetByName(newDatabaseName).Model;

Is there a more reliable way to snag the GUID that is created when this model is created?
I expect to get the model details (including GUID) when I run the code.
I have tried this:
Model newWorkItemDataset = server.Databases.GetByName(newDatabaseName).Model;

and this:
string xmlaQuery = @"
    <Discover xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis'>
        <RequestType>MDSCHEMA_CUBES</RequestType>
        <Restrictions>
            <RestrictionList>
                <CUBE_NAME>YourSemanticModelName</CUBE_NAME>
            </RestrictionList>
        </Restrictions>
        <Properties>
            <PropertyList>
                <Catalog>YourWorkspaceId</Catalog>
            </PropertyList>
        </Properties>
    </Discover>";

using (AdomdConnection connection = new AdomdConnection($"DataSource={workspaceConnection};User ID=app:{ApplicationId}@{Tenant};Password={ApplicationSecret};"))
{
    connection.Open();

    var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = xmlaQuery;

    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            string semanticModelGuid = reader["CUBE_GUID"].ToString();
            Console.WriteLine($"Semantic Model GUID: {semanticModelGuid}");
        }
    }
}



neither works

What is the error that you are getting?
